# I can't connect to SQL Server inside container

Tags: sql-server, docker, ubuntu

This is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: "3.9"
services: 
    api:
        # configuration of API here
    db:
        image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server
        restart: always
        container_name: Database
        volumes:
            - ./Data:/var/opt/mssql
        environment: 
            - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
            - SA_PASSWORD=lksU2o412f7tBj58t07B
            - MSSQL_PID=Express
        ports:
            - 1433:1433
        command: >
            sh -c
            "
            tail -f /dev/null
            "
```

As you can see, I'm using the official docker image for MS SQL Server, `mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server`.

My laptop is `Ubuntu 20.04 LTS`.

I run `docker-compose up -d` and then `docker exec -it db sh` to get interactive shell.

Then I write this command:

`/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P 'lksU2o412f7tBj58t07B'`

And I get this response:

> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Login timeout expired.
> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : TCP Provider: Error code 0x2749.
> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online..

This is the official image and I have not changed anything.

Also in my `api` container, I can ping `db` or `Database`. But I can't telnet port `1433`.

Also from my host machine I can `telnet localhost 1433`, but I get this response:

> Trying 127.0.0.1...
> Connected to localhost.
> Escape character is '^]'.
> Connection closed by foreign host.

This is a terrible experience in working with containers from Microsoft. Aren't containers supposed to work out of the box? Isn't container technology there only to solve these stupid problems?

What should I do?

Comment: It looks like you're overriding the SQL Server image's default [command](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#command), `/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr`. Does it improve if you remove `command: sh -c "tail -f /dev/null"` from your `docker-compose.yml` file?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, your comment helped me, and I also realized that I have to run SQL Server Docker in `root` user from [here](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-docker/issues/615#issuecomment-755343546)