# How to run command on container startup, without overriding original image's commands?

Tags: sql-server, docker

In my [previous quesiton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68120898/i-cant-connect-to-sql-server-inside-container) I realized that if I add `command` to my `docker-compose.yml` for Microsoft SQL Server image, I override their `CMD [ "/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr" ]` which is in their [`Dockerfile`](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-docker/blob/master/linux/mssql-server-linux/Dockerfile).

But I want to automate some processes on my container startup.

For example, when I develop a module in ASP.NET Core, I want to create a database based on a convention in my database container and apply migrations and database seeding automatically.

Now that I can't run `command` on my container in my `docker-compose.yml`, what other options do I have to run commands on my container's startup?

Answer (score 2):

From the [official mssql-server dockerhub page](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server):

> You can also use the tools in an entrypoint.sh script to do things like create databases or logins, attach databases, import data, or other setup tasks. See this example of [using an entrypoint.sh script to create a database and schema and bcp in some data](https://github.com/twright-msft/mssql-node-docker-demo-app)."

I would advice sticking to the approach suggested on the dockerhub site.

Comment: I saw that repo, and to be honest, it's unclean. I don't want to have another `Dockerfile` and then `entrypoint.sh` and then `setup.sql` per project. I have a central `docker-compose.yml` file that is shared across many similar modules. And I don't want to repeat myself with 4 files per module, which means almost 200 files per 50 modules. That's a maintenance nightmare. But thank you for this note.

Comment: You do not need 50 `entrypopint.sh`'s. Write one `entrypoint.sh`, that checks whether, for example, scripts in an `init`-folder exist and run this scripts at startup. That is, for example, how the postgres docker image does things (see its [dockerhub-documentation, section "Initialization scripts"](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres) for an example). This way, you only need to specify the setup scripts necessary for the specific service (i.e. setup database user and the database, possibly the database schema if you do not use a tool like flyway or liquibase for database schema versioning).